# Arrange $_POST to multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have an form when submitting the form and if print  $_POST  i will get the output like the following

```
    [type] =>'new',
[class] =>'10',
[div] =>c,
[id_228] => 228,
[title_228]=> First,
[colour_228]=> red,
[id_229] => 229,
[title_229]=> second,
[colour_229]=> blue,
[id_230] => 230,
[title_230]=> third,
[colour_230]=> yellow,
[id_231] => 231,
[title_231]=> fourth,
[colour_231]=> orange,
```

etc

now i have to store this output to an  result array . Please see the result array

```
result_array[1]=array("Title", 'Color')
```

so in this result array i have to add $_POST like this

```
result_array[228]=array("First","red")
result_array[229]=array("Second","blue")
result_array[230]=array("Third","yellow")
result_array[231]=array("Fourth","red")
```

Please help .

Comment: is this from a form? you should have placed the id in the name attribute on the inputs, then you wouldn't have to do any array modifications anymore, ala `name="input[<id here>][name]`

Comment: Exactly what Ghost said. This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa). Your input data is in a bad format to be processed more.

Comment: this is output of a complicated form created by other . Now i am troubleshooting . Please help

Comment: yes i know this is xyproblem . But for the time being i have to solve this . After this we will try to change the form later .

Comment: Explode names by `_` and decide what to do.

Comment: You still haven't specified what the logic is, or what you have tried. By the looks of it, you're ignoring the ID, which I imagine is important? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: the logic is a ,  for loop in which we can  loop the result_array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First step should be creating a proper looking array out of this data:
https://3v4l.org/r0HZ9

```
$post = [
    'id_228' => 228,
    'title_228' => "First",
    'colour_228' => 'red',

    'id_229' => 228,
    'title_229' => "Second",
    'colour_229' => 'blue'];


// Transform data into a proper format
$resultArray = [];
foreach($post as $key => $val) {
    $key = explode('_',$key);
    $resultArray[$key[1]][$key[0]] = $val;
}

// Now do whatever you want to do 
var_dump($resultArray);
```

Now you could add more logic... If you want the data in your proposed format you could do

```
$result = [];
foreach($resultArray as $item) { 
    $result[] = [$item['title'], $item['colour']];
}
```

https://3v4l.org/WC2B0

**EDIT:**
Since you added

```
[type] =>'new',
[class] =>'10',
[div] =>c,
```

you might want to create a list of allowed fields that should be added, maybe something like:

```
// Transform data into a proper format
$resultArray = [];
$allowedFields = ['id', 'title', 'colour'];
foreach($post as $key => $val) {
    $key = explode('_',$key);
    if(in_array($key[0], $allowedFields)) {
        $resultArray[$key[1]][$key[0]] = $val;
    }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/NQGfa

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to just loop it and prepare a new array.

```
$result = array();
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    list($title, $key) = explode('_', $key);
    if (!is_array($result[$key])) $result[$key] = array();

    $result[$key][$title] = $value;
}

var_dump($result);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: but what is $title here ?   list($title, $key)

Comment: the title refers to your array_key whose values will be one of id, title or color. Its just a name that I have given, you can change it as per your convenience.

Answer (score 2):

```
$arr= ["id_228" => 228, "title_228" => "First",
"colour_228"=> "red",
"id_229" => 229,
"title_229"=> "second",
"colour_229"=> "blue",
"id_230" => 230,
"title_230"=> "third",
"colour_230"=> "yellow",
"id_231" => 231,
"title_231"=> "fourth",
"colour_231"=> "orange" ];

foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
    $d = explode( '_', $key );
    if(true == is_numeric( $value)) {
        continue;
    }
    $c[$d[1]][]= $value ;
}
print_r($c);
```

Out put

```
Array
(
    [228] => Array
        (
            [0] => First
            [1] => red
        )

    [229] => Array
        (
            [0] => second
            [1] => blue
        )

    [230] => Array
        (
            [0] => third
            [1] => yellow
        )

    [231] => Array
        (
            [0] => fourth
            [1] => orange
        )

)
```